# What is the difference between . ./ ./* in linux

Tags: linux, bash

when i copy files,  execute the file in linux, I am Not quite understand the difference and how to use them.

please help. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` means current directory
`./` means current directory, too
`./*` means all files in current directory

Comment: when I use 'adb push . /sdcard/' in Terminal, . and ./ is ok, but ./* will not work. I don't know why.

Comment: @punan What is the error ?

Comment: @punan That's probably because of the way [shell globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) works and the fact that adb is very simplistic when it comes to interpreting arguments.

Answer (score 0):

`.` means the current directory, and `./` is the same but more explicit, saying "Hey, I'm a directory!" It's like any other folder: `TheFolder` and `TheFolder/` refer to the same object. One case where the meaning is different is when looking at a symlink pointing at a directory: `TheLink` can refer either to the link object or the directory that you pointed at, depending on the situation, while `TheLink/` will always refer to the directory. Also, when you run the `rsync` command, it will treat `TheFolder` and `TheFolder/` differently.

`./*` just means all the files in the current directory, same as `*`. Bash expands that asterisk before the command is run, so the program doesn't see the asterisk, instead seeing all the files as arguments. The difference between these two is that for the former, the command will see "./" prepended to each filename.

To see how these differ, `echo` is a safe command to run. It will just print the value of what you send it:

```
echo *
echo ./*
```

Answer (score 0):

`.` and `./` both mean current working directory

`../` means parent directory of the current working directory

`./*` means all files and directories in current working directory plus all files and directories in all directories in the current working directory.

Answer (score -1):

./* is all files in current directory
./ is current directory